# Remove link border from around image

Tags: 2010, hyperlink, image-display

For SP2010, how do you remove the ugly blue border from images that have a link on them? I've tried adding `style="border:0"` on the anchor tag but to no avail. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to apply the style to the IMG, not the HREF.

This will show the blue border (at least in IE and Firefox, Chrome doesn't)

```
<a href="http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com">
   <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/sharepoint/img/logo.png">
</a>
```

Neither of these will, first using the 'old style' border attribute

```
<a href="http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com">
   <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/sharepoint/img/logo.png" border="0">
</a>
```

Next using inline styles

```
<a href="http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com">
   <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/sharepoint/img/logo.png" style="border:none;">
</a>
```

And using CSS to take off the border for all images

```
<style>
   a img {border:none}
</style>
<a href="http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com">
   <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/sharepoint/img/logo.png">
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, Ryan. That worked like a charm :) And thank you for the detailed instructions.

Comment: Awesome! Been struggling with it for hours, can't believe the answer it's so simple :)

Comment: @Jireh I went ahead and converted your answer to a comment. With a bit more reputation, you will be able to [post comments everywhere](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: thanks Ryan! Much better than Microsoft Support answer of border="0" which did not work and got me frustrated.

Comment: For all Clickable items (links included) you could also go further to disable the "selection box" when you click on by using "outline-style:none" attribute.

Comment: Is it possible to apply this stylesheet code inside of a content editor web part?

Comment: @TempaC - yes it is

Answer (score 2):

Add a Content Editor Webpart to the affected page.  Edit the HTML for the webpart.  Paste in the following text:

```
<style>
   a img {border:none}
</style>
```

This will remove borders from all images with links on the page.

Answer (score 2):

Within SharePoint Designer right click on the image's web part and select picture properties, select appearance and change border thickness to 0 and the blue border disappears.

Answer (score 1):

Your styling the wrong element, you need to style the links.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

You can view styles applied by using the IE Developer tool, FireBug in Firefox, or Chrome developer tool.

Good blogs to keep bookmarked:

http://blog.drisgill.com/

http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/

Comment: Are you sure about that? I think you should be styling the IMG not the LINK.

Comment: I didn't have a chance to check this yesterday, Ryan is correct you will need to override the IMG child element of the the anchor tag "a".

Answer (score 1):

Click on site actions (top left corner of screen)
Go to : Site settings - Look and feel - site theme
Change the selected color for the "followed Hyperlink" to white (color code is #F8F8F8)
Click apply.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code and it worked:

```
<img src="image.png" alt="Trust Pilot" border="0px" style="border:none!important; outline:none!important;">
```

The border is created from the outline attribute just make sure you have it as none.
I hope this will help someone else