# SharePoint 2010: Removing link border around image using the content editor web part

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, css, content-editor-web-part

In addition to topic [Remove link border from around image](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16426/remove-link-border-from-around-image), I was wondering if it were possible to remove all the borders around linked images on a page using the content editor web part?

I've added the content editor web part to the bottom of my page and added the following stylesheet code:

```
<style>
   a img {border:none}
</style>
```

However, the stylesheet code is not applied to the page since the borders are still around the images.

Is what I'm trying even possible?

Comment: Yes this is possible... I would make sure you are doing this in the style-sheet rather than within a web-part.

Comment: You're right. I've created a stylesheet, added it to the site assets and linked to it in my content editor web part. Now it works.

Comment: I would add it into the Master page rather than the web part..refer to this post for more info..http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60090/sharepoint-site-using-corev4-and-custom-css-file/60097#60097

Comment: Stephen add your comment as an answer!